# If variable exists, display input textfield value, otherwise display placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-templates

In Angular 1.2.19, is there are ternary operator for the templates which would allow me to display a variable is an input value, if it exists, and if not, then just display the placeholder?

Kinda like this:

```
<input type="text "{{ if phoneNumber ? "value='{{phoneNumber}}'" : "placeholder='{{ language.placeHolder}}'"}}
```

Edit: Here's my current HTML:

```
<input type="text"name="buyPhoneNumber" id="buyPhoneNumber" value="{{ phoneNumber }}" 
class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="{{language.phoneNumberHolder}}"
                       ng-model="buyObj.pinOrPhonenumber"
                       ng-change="buyChange();"
                       on-change-phone-number/>
```

Comment: Why bother conditionally adding a placeholder? Add it, and it'll only show up when there's no input. The work's already done for you.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein For some reason the placeholder seems to be prioritised, and shows up even when there is an input value. Am using latest Chrome

Comment: @SatoBolin Can you show us how you attempted to use the placeholder originally?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Have updated my question with the code I currently use

Answer (score 1):

Use an Angular mustache expression and [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue):

```
<input ng-value="{{ phoneNumber }}" placeholder="{{ phoneNumber ? language.placeHolder : '' }}" />
```

The mustache expression is regular JavaScript, so you can use normal ternary expression.

You can also hide the placeholder via CSS:

```
input:focus::-webkit-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with ng-model instead of ng-value.